# Delete the right data using post

Tags: php

I have this code. i just want to delete the record that i want to delete but when i click the button delete it only delete the last data record added what should i do ? Thankyou in advance

```
  if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
     $id = $_POST['delete_rec_id'];  
       $query=mysqli_query($link,"Delete from hgrecord where PossibleCondition  ='".$id."' ");
   }

 if(isset($_GET["poscon"])){
     $kwery=mysqli_query($link,"select Distinct PossibleCondition from  hgrecord where PatientId='".$session."' and Date='".$new_time."' order by PossibleCondition");
     while($rr=mysqli_fetch_array($kwery)){
                 $PatientId=$rr["PatientId"];

         $condition1=$rr["PossibleCondition"];



                 if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['sym1']) && in_array($condition1,$_POST['sym1']))
            $strIsChecked='checked="checked"';
        else
            $strIsChecked=null;

                 echo '<br><td><input type="checkbox" '.$strIsChecked.' title ="'.$otherspec1.'" name="sym1[]"  onclick="javascript: submit()" value ="'.$condition1.'"></td>';
  echo '<td align="">'.$condition1.'</td>';


       ?>


 <button type="submit" name="delete"  aria-label="Left Align">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="delete_rec_id" value="<?php print $condition1;


            ?>"/>



 <?php } } ?>
```

Comment: Where's your `HTML` form tag?

Comment: in the top of my file did not include

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add your `form` tag around each set of button and hidden input:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="delete"  aria-label="Left Align">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
    <input type="hidden" name="delete_rec_id" value="<?php print $condition1;" />
</form>
```

Otherwise you'll have one form with multiple hidden inputs with `name="delete_rec_id"`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are doing in your javascript function `javascript: submit()`

What I can suggest it, add the functionality in your javascript function to collect(comma separated values) all the checked checkboxes and assign it to the hidden field `delete_rec_id`.